# Why an executable running in shell output to stdout instead of stderr when crashes?

Tags: c++, shell

I wrote a C++ demo `test.cpp` like:

```
int main()
{
    int num = 1 / 0;
}
```

then compiled it

```
$ g++ test.cpp -o test
```

then run it in shell:

```
$ ./test 2>error.txt
```

I expected the error messages to be redirected to error.txt, but they still print on the screen through stdout. Why did that happen?

The output shows as below:

```
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

Comment: g++ 5.1.0 release mode (-O2) gave compilation warning(s) but __no__ runtime error (might have optimized out all the code).  What output are you seeing?

Comment: The output was added. I didn't use -O2 and the error did occurred.

Comment: Compile C++ program with a C compiler???

Comment: Message translates as _"Exceptions to floating-point numbers"_ __except__ your question is integer division.

Comment: Got same result when using g++. @iBug

Comment: @RichardCritten I believe its `Floating poinr exception (core dumped)`, lol.

Comment: @iBug yep. `g++` is just `gcc` with some flags to link with the standard library and such. Since the program is dead simple and self-contained, it works without it.

Comment: @Quentin I absolutely know what you say. Despute that, it should still be *heavily* discouraged to use a C compiler on a C++ program. We like to point out every mistake, don't we?

Comment: @iBug well, it is still a C++ compiler unless you pass in `-x c`. But maybe use less question marks in your affirmations :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the error message is **not** generated by the program. It is generated by the operating system.

Think: the program has died already. How can it generate extra output?

In fact, you'll observe output even if you redirect **both** stdout and stderr **of the program** to `/dev/null`.

If you create a sub-shell and redirect its stderr, you'll see the error message redirected:

```
( ./test ) 2>error.txt
```

Comment: Wow, amazing. Why the output does not belong to stdout or stderr?

Comment: It does go to stderr, but you have not redirected **this** output. You have only redirected the output of the program. Execute it in a subshell, i.e. `(  ./test  ) 2>/dev/null` (don't forget the spaces around the parenthesis!), and the output should disappear.

Comment: @user1934428 Perfect explaination! I understand now. This also explains why error in python script can directly show. Interpretative language scripts can directly output error by itself, but compiled language can only print errors by it's parent script.

Comment: @jinge Error messages in interpreted languages are generated by the interpreter program, so the program controls the output. In case the program crashes, the crash message is still geenrated by the operating system.